# Nested itemize in beamer while only first layer bullet-points appear one-by-one

Tags: beamer, itemize

I have two nested lists in a beamer presentation,i.e

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item a
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{itemize}
\item b
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now, in both layers, the different items appear one-by-one, whereas I only want the items of the first layer(letters) to appear one-by one and the ones in the second itemize(numbers) all together. How could I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Supplying `<+->` sets the stepping environment until the end of the `itemize`.

To easily let two items show themselves together do:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item a
  \item<.->
\end{itemize}
```

The `.` tells the item, to *not* increment the slide counter.

This works fine for single items, however, if you use nested levels like this:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item a
  \begin{itemize}[<.->]
    \item 1
    ...
    \item 10
   \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

you will find that `a` and `1 -- 10` are shown together. This is probably not what you want. For tweaking there is an optional argument to the counter argument `.(#)` where `#` is a number. If you specify `<.(1)->` it will be equivalent to adding `1` to the slide where it will be shown. Hence the trick is to step the counter *and* force it to not increment:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item a
  \begin{itemize}[<.(1)->]
    \item 1
    ...
    \item 10
  \end{itemize}
  \pause
  \item z
\end{itemize}
```

The second pause is a local step counter. One would think you can use it instead of the `(1)` notation, however the nested list complicates things and the above method is more lenient.

Comment: What about \begin{itemize}[<+->]...\item ... \begin{itemize}[<.->] \item[<+->]...\item ... \item ... \end{itemize}\item...\item\end{itemize}?